# How to retain the rows in file B for which the corresponding value in column L(B) is greater than the corresponding value in column L(A) of file A?

Tags: awk

I am working with 2 distinct bed files with the same structure (thousands of rows and 10 columns). In particular I would need to keep only the rows of file B that satisfy the following condition: the value in the last column of file B (right) must be greater than the corresponding value in the last column of file A (left). In the example below I should retain only rows `a` and `c`. I am wondering if there is an efficient awk script to solve this. Thank you.

```
     A B C D E F G H I L                A B C D E F G H I L
a    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1            a   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 2
b    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3            b   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 3
c    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 6            c   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 8
d    0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4            d   0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
awk 'NR==FNR {a[NR]=$NF; next} (a[FNR] < $NF){print}' file-a.txt file-b.txt
```

1. 'NR'(line number) is ordinal number # NR will be 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8; we need only first 4 to collect in array from first file-a;
2. FNR(line number) is like ordinar number, it will count lines for file-a 1..4 then when it come to file-b it will again start counting from 1..4; NFR == (file-a: 1,2,3,4; file-b: 1,2,3,4;)
3. 'next' read this [link](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Next-Statement.html)

Comment: Many thanks, but sorry I can't understand  why only first 5 are needed.

Comment: @MassimoFaggiani Hehehe because when I tested on my PC, I didn't remove first line in every file.. that is why I talk about 5, it need to be 4 in comment.. My stupid error brain got confused :-D